# How to debug WebApplicationInitializer/onStartUp method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am new to java web development. When I try to debug the web application using intellij I can not make my webpage hit breakpoint on onStartUp method. Could it be setup issue, or how I run my web application?

Comment: `onStartup` is called _once_, **at startup**.

Comment: yes I understand that but how to make it hit there during deployment or something like that.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint somewhere inside it and start your app in debug mode. (This assumes that you're set up with newer version of Tomcat which uses the initializer.)